# Forwarding Events of Different Type

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I'm trying to forward events from one class to objects contained within it (as described here: [Forwarding events in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065355/forwarding-events-in-c-sharp)).  However, the events are of different type.

For example, I have a class `Item` which exposes a `ValueChanged` event handler of type `EventHandler`.  The class `ItemHaver` exposes an `EventHandler<StatusEventArgs>`, which should fire whenever `Item.ValueChanged` does, but should also provide additional information.  How do I properly implement `add/remove` to the `ItemValueChanged` event declaration?

In the below code, would the lambda function in the `add` method perform the correct action, and if so, what's the proper way to handle the `remove`?

```
class Item
{
    public event EventHandler ValueChanged;
}

class ItemHaver
{
    private int _status;
    private Item _item;

    public event EventHandler<StatusEventArgs> ItemValueChanged
    {
        add 
        { 
            _item.ValueChanged += value; // Wrong type
            _item.ValueChanged += 
                (obj, e) => value(obj, new StatusEventArgs(this._status));
        }
        remove 
        { 
            _item.ValueChanged -= // Does this even work?
                (obj, e) => value(obj, new StatusEventArgs(this._status));  
        }
    }
}

class StatusEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    int Status { get; private set; }
    StatusEventArgs(int status) { Status = status; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try using a dictionary in which I map the handlers.

```
class ItemHaver
{
    private int _status;
    private Item _item;

    private Dictionary<EventHandler<StatusEventArgs>, EventHandler> handlersMap = new Dictionary<EventHandler<StatusEventArgs>, EventHandler>();

    public event EventHandler<StatusEventArgs> ItemValueChanged
    {
        add
        {
            // _item.ValueChanged += value; // Wrong type
            handlersMap.Add(value, (obj, e) => value(obj, new StatusEventArgs(this._status)));
            _item.ValueChanged += handlersMap[value];
        }
        remove
        {
            _item.ValueChanged -= handlersMap[value];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. I actually performed a deeper refactoring and changed the underlying EventHandler on the `Item` class to match what was expected (the actual code involved many different types of `Item`, all developed in C# prior to generics.  In any case, I can't comment on the efficiency of your method, but it did work as a temporary fix.